# PreferenceManager doesn't change value for Preference choice

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making an app that uses a Preferences and allows the user to pick if they want to specifically only use Wifi Only for data transfers. I followed the documentation 
 [Manage Network Usage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing)
but some of the instructions were deprecated so I had to improvise. One thing that was still part of the example was 
`SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sPref = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_NETWORK_TYPE, "First");`

And it's supposed to default to the phone's default network settings until the user changes them or in my case, I chose for the "any" option to be default but it doesn't save the change.

I don't understand something and I can't find a straight online. What did I miss in the code?

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
static final String TAG = "SettingsActivity";
public static final String WIFI = "WiFi";
public static final String FIRST = "First";

public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String WIFI_CONNECTION = "WiFi";
public static final String CELLULAR_CONNECTION = "Cellular";
public static final String WIFI_PREFERENCE = "WiFi Enabled";
public static final String NO_PREFERENCE = "First Enabled";

public static final String NO_CONNECTION = "No Connection";

public static final String PREF_NETWORK_TYPE = "network_choice";

public static String sPref = null;

private NetworkCheck networkCheck = new NetworkCheck();
private static boolean prefWifi = false;
private static boolean noPreferredNetwork = true;
private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
private static boolean cellularConnected = false;
public static boolean networkConnected = true;

//TODO: Figure out what this needs and implement it. How do I fix the settings menu?

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.root_preferences, false);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    networkCheck = new NetworkCheck();
    this.registerReceiver(networkCheck, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (networkCheck != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(networkCheck);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, prefWifi + " " + noPreferredNetwork, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sPref = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_NETWORK_TYPE, "First");
    Toast.makeText(this, prefWifi + " " + noPreferredNetwork, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //checkNetworkFlags(this);
    networkType();
}

public void networkType() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(WIFI_PREFERENCE, prefWifi);
    editor.putBoolean(NO_PREFERENCE, noPreferredNetwork);
    editor.putBoolean(NO_CONNECTION, networkConnected);
    editor.apply();
}
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        if (key.equals(PREF_NETWORK_TYPE)) {
            prefWifi = WIFI.equals(sPref);
            noPreferredNetwork = FIRST.equals(sPref);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you finish editing the data inside a Shared preference you need to call the property .commit after finish or it'll not save the date, I hope this can help you :D

Comment: Apply and commit work the same essentially. It still doesn't explain why the variable `sPrefs` doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Your saving or putting your data to a different sharedPreference from the one your reading or getting from.

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

is different from
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Choose on to use throughout your activity or application

Comment: I can't use two instances? I fixed it to mkae one instance of the call but that still doesn't solve the problem. The sPref doesn't cchange it's value during use. When I change the setting from any network to wifi, there is no change.